How do I use an SVG image in a webImageControl, tms web core
I am trying to put a phone SVG image into a TWebImageControl in the .pas unit.
I tried adding the image to the TWebImageControl with code that executes on the creation of the application.
PhoneWIC.Picture := <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="IconSize" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--FA--><path d="M164.9 24.6c-7.7-18.6-28-28.5-47.4-23.2l-88 24C12.1 30.2 0 46 0 64C0 311.4 200.6 512 448 512c18 0 33.8-12.1 38.6-29.5l24' + '-88c5.3-19.4-4.6-39.7-23.2-47.4l-96-40c-16.3-6.8-35.2-2.1-46.3 11.6L304.7 368C234.3 334.7 177.3 277.7 144 207.3L193.3 167c13.7-11.2 18.4-30 11.6-46.3l-40-96z"/></svg>;

But it doesn't work.

https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/svg-support-in-web-core/22451

Here's an example where I load a phone SVG into a TWebImageControl using the SVG Code:
var
  SVGCode: String;
begin
  SVGCode := '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M164.9 24.6c-7.7-18.6-28-28.5-47.4-23.2l-88 24C12.1 30.2 0 46 0 64C0 311.4 200.6 512 448 512c18 0 33.8-12.1 38.6-29.5l24-88c5.3-19.4-4.6-39.7-23.2-47.4l-96-40c-16.3-6.8-35.2-2.1-46.3 11.6L304.7 368C234.3 334.7 177.3 277.7 144 207.3L193.3 167c13.7-11.2 18.4-30 11.6-46.3l-40-96z"/></svg>';
  WebImageControl1.URL := 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(SVGCode);
end;

